# Objective-C: Sharpen images created with CGContextdrawPDFPage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, cgcontextdrawpdfpage

I create UIImages from pdf with CGContextDrawPDFPage.

The quality wasn´t satisfying so I tried

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context,kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

and it worked out. But the quality of the resulting images is still not good enough. The image looks totally blurry on the iPad.

How can I increase the quality and sharpen the image a bit?

Comment: What size are the PDF pages you're creating and how are you creating / showing the images?

Comment: The pdf pages have a width of 1683 and a height of 595. I create the images using CGContextDrawImagePDFPage and then save them to a file using [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get better results by using

**UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions**

instead of

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

for beginning the image context.

The parameter scale set to 0.0 did the trick.